# How convert array of interface to float

Tags: go, type-conversion

```
bound :=  []interface{}{1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00}
new_bound := bound.([]float32)
log.Println(new_bound)
```

How convert array of interface to array of float?

> invalid type assertion: bound.([]float32) (non-interface type []interface {} on left)

And in real project

> panic: interface conversion: interface is []interface {}, not []float32

Comment: Just a general Go comment: If this is code trying to be "generic" just give up on generics in Go. Using the `interface{}` stuff is much worse than Java `Object`. It is slow, difficult to get right, leads to many bugs and code panics, etc. If you need a lot of similar code for different types write a code generator instead...my opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example you have a slice where each item it contains is an `interface{}` rather than say, a single `interface{}` representing a `[]float32`, for this reason you can't convert the whole collection so simply like that. Instead you have to iterate it and do a type assertion on each item in the collection. Here's an example; https://play.golang.org/p/dD4161xgaV

```
bound :=  []interface{}{1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00}
new_bound := []float64{}
for _, v := range bound {
     new_bound = append(new_bound, v.(float64))
}
```

One other thing to note, those literals have their type implied and it's `float64` so you actually need that here.

EDIT: Including this more optimized solution posted by OneOfOne;

```
func main() {
    bound := []interface{}{1.00, 1.10, 1.11, 1.111}
    new_bound := make([]float64, len(bound))
    for i := range bound {
        new_bound[i] = bound[i].(float64)
    }
    fmt.Println(new_bound)

}
```

Comment: @OneOfOne good call. Hope you don't mind me including that in the answer here.

Comment: Not a problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to iterate over your slice and append each item to a new slice. In order to append it to your []float32, you will need to type assert:

```
bound := []interface{}{1.00, 1.00, 1.00, 1.00}
new_bound := make([]float32, 0, len(bound))
for _, v := range bound {
    new_bound = append(new_bound, v.(float32))
}
```

GoPlay here:
https://play.golang.org/p/S8-4KJkqPq